# Unstable Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 22.04 (Dell XPS)

Tags: wireless

I'm experiencing very unstable wifi on my ubuntu 22.04 installed on my Dell XPS 15 9520.
Wifi either doesn't connect or disconnects very soon.

My laptop has this wifi card:
Intel(R) Killer(TM) Wi-Fi 6 1675 (AX211) 2x2 + Bluetooth 5.2 Wireless Card

Probably something with drivers... but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any guess what could be causing this?

Comment: i have the same laptop xps 9520. Wifi seems to work better with recent kernels like 5.18 or 5.19 (install its with mainline).
Your touchpad dont have lag in randoms times?
I have this touchpad and don't find solution yet.

Comment: I found that installing a backport iwlwifi dkms driver improved wifi performance. But, I might update the kernel to see if that further improves it because it is still a bit slow some times.
I also have issues with touchpad lagg. Another issue I have is that graphics tend to be slow when running intensive graphic apps that use OpenGL.

Comment: Have you tried following for the touchpad?
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000150104/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix