# Unstable wlan / wifi with Ubuntu 22.04 + Dell XPS 13 (9315)

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, dell, xps

I basically have the same issues described in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422058/unstable-wi-fi-on-ubuntu-22-04-dell-xps).

So my wireless Network connection is constantly reseting. That means that different applications are telling me that there is no internet connection and then my wifi icon on gnome shows first a question mark, disappears and is then reconnected. And that happens about every minute.

I would provide more informations but im not sure where to begin.

Device: Dell XPS 13 (9315)
Wifi card: Killer AX1650 (2x2) basierend auf Intel WiFi 6 + Bluetooth 5.1
OS: Ubuntu 22.04

**Edit:**
Weirdly after (unsuccessfully) trying different mainline Kernel this issue resolved itself. I'm not sure how...

Comment: Ah, very likely it's a firmware issue. Did you check dmesg to see if your firmware was crashing during the disconnects? I experience this regularly on my 9370